# admin page not working after moving magento 2 directory

Tags: magento2

I installed magento 2 in a directory jle2.aaefe.org and got it working with the addons etc I needed.  to go live I rename the directory to jle.aaefe.org. I change the URLs in the system setup and the frontend is now working fine.  I cannot access the admin page now.  When I type in the url for the admin page I get

"Whoops, our bad...
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated."

The frontend is working fine I just need to get to the admin panel.  I am not a programmer so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: check env.php inside app/etc/env.php 'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ], add in url what is added on your frontName

Comment: I looked at that file and the info was 'backend' => ['frontName' => 'admin123'], which is what I used to get to the admin panel before the directory was renamed. I also tried 'backend' => ['frontName' => 'https://jle.aaefe.org/admin123'], but that did not work either.

Comment: i ran info:adminuri and it returned admin123 so I am totally lost

Answer (score 0):

First check web/unsecure/base_url value in core_config_data table in magento databse.Value should contain pub so the value of this url should be like:

http://localhost/magento2/pub

If not then correct it and second check admin frontname in app/etc/env.php file so at the end final url should be base_url + admin frontname that is:

http://localhost/magento2/pub/adminFrontName

Hit this url in browser you will see admin login page.